# SLES 11 SDK repositories

Tags: linux, repository, sles

is there a way to add SLES 11 SDK repositories without having to download and burn the ISO ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can add a repository that is from a remote source such as ftp or http.

Go into yast (enter yast at the command prompt) and then **Software > Software Repositories**

Use **[Add]** to add a new repository and you should see the various sources from there.

Comment: …except that just adding the repo URL for SDK won't be enough, because it won't contain the opaque authentication token that's different for each repo that requires a valid SUSE subscription.

Answer (score 1):

You can also download the ISO and mount it directly with "mount -o loop sdk1.iso" and then add it as a repository in YaST, saving the burn step.   In the "Software->Software Repositories->Repository", click "Add" and there is a "Local ISO Image" selection.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually possible. I followed the steps at https://www.novell.com/support/kb/doc.php?id=7015337 and it seems (at least for now) that the repositories are activated.

In my case, I wanted the SLE11SP3 version of the SDK, which matches the article; if you are interested in a different version, you might have to do a bit of guesswork to find the right RPMs for your release (assuming they're available at all).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the link [shared by @koniiiik](https://serverfault.com/a/726817/59287), I found out that in YaST2 you can add following repository for accessing packages of SLES 11 SDK without downloading it all in an .iso: https://nu.novell.com/repo/$RCE/SLE11-SDK-SP4-Pool/sle-11-x86_64 (change "SP4" if you have a different SP).

When asked for credentials insert the ones you can find on [SUSE Customer Center](https://scc.suse.com) > Organization > Organization Credentials.

I don't know if you need to register your SLES or not for this to work (I did it).